# How to delay each loop iteration to create sequential effect?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add a delay inside a `forEach` so you can see a slight delay as each span `innerHTML` is swapped out in order. At the moment my loop happens, the relative span gets injected but the loop is that quick that all the letters appear at the same time. Would be nice to delay each inject by 200ms if possible, I'm just drawing a blank on how to do this.

**JS Snippet**

```
function showCity() {
    newStringArr = cities[i].split('');

    var tickerSpans = ticker.children;      
    newStringArr.forEach(function(letter, idx) {

        // Delay each assignment by 200ms?
        tickerSpans[idx].innerHTML = letter;

    });

    i++;

    if(i <= 2) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            randomWordInterval = setInterval(randomiser, SPEED, false);
        }, PAUSE);
    }
}
```

Code link http://codepen.io/styler/pen/jPPRyy?editors=001

Comment: You'd have to do something like first loop through make it setTimeout to run in 200ms, second set it to 400ms, 3rd 600ms, etc. JavaScript is essentially single threaded. There is no "sleep" method. Of course that wouldn't be 100% accurate, since the second one might need to really be 399.9ms, not 400ms because some time has been taken between each loop iteration. If you're animating 10 chars, it won't be noticeable. If you're animating 10 million chars, it will be.

Comment: So wrap the innerHTML assignment in a setTimeout, use the idx * setTimeout duration. Something like that?

Comment: Yes, EXCEPT, make sure you're careful because of closures. You should  pass the letter variable and idx to a function that calls setTimeout. Otherwise you'll quickly discover that no animation happens because every iteration will receive the "last" value of letter due to the fact that the function runs asynchronously :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always <strike>create a function that just continues to call itself until it reaches the end of the array</strike> use recursion:

```
function createHtml(array, index, elems) {
    elems[index].innerHTML = array[index++];
    if ((index + 1) <= array.length) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            createHtml(array, index, elems);
        }, 200);
    }
}

var newStringArr = cities[i].split('');
var tickerSpans = ticker.children;

createHtml(newStringArr, 0, tickerSpans);
```

Working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqPjqe